# Sublime custom snippet not displaying code hints in popup

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm just new in Sublime and I just created a new snippet saved in an HTML folder. My problem is the created snippet doesn't display the auto-complete box. I need to type the whole word in tab-trigger, then hitting tab twice. Below, you'll see it working in JavaScript syntax.

[image]

```
 <snippet> 
     <content><![CDATA[ <ccbn:html-block> ${1} </ccbn:html-block> ]]></content>
     <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
     <tabTrigger>hblock</tabTrigger> 
     <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
     <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> --> 
 </snippet>
```

Comment: please provide the code inline with your question.

Comment: hey jay, see below my snippet. it is actually working but like I said, I needed to type the whole word "hblock" and then hit tab twice. 


<snippet>
 <content><![CDATA[
<ccbn:html-block>
 ${1}
</ccbn:html-block>
]]></content>
 <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
 <tabTrigger>hblock</tabTrigger>
 <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
 <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>

Answer (score 0):

If you want the snippet to kick in when you're editing HTML, then I think you need to change your snippet's `<scope>` to text.html